# GitCandy cannot create repository when it is deployed

Tags: git, iis, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I successfully compiled and tested GitCandy from Visual Studio and IIS Express. However when I deploy it to a non Express IIS, the repository creation fails. I added some extra error logging to the file operations on the GitCandy source level.

What I see is this:

```
>> 04/11/2015 13:46:37.964 -07:00 Error, LibGit2Sharp.NameConflictException:
Failed to make directory 'c:/Users/Csaba/Documents': Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_init_ext(FilePath workdirPath, FilePath gitdirPath, Boolean isBare)
at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Init(String path, Boolean isBare)
```

`GitCandy` calls `LibGit2Sharp` with the correct repository full path (in my case `c:\Users\Csaba\Documents\GCD\Repositories\GCT1`) and `isBare` is set to `true`.

So it's doesn't make sense why libgit2 would try to create a parent folder. It's absolutely true though that the Document folder already exists. Before I start to dig into the guts of LibGit2Sharp and then libgit2, I wonder if anyone else seen this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is related to a ancient issue (**[#795](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/795)**) which has been fixed since.

I'd suggest you to ping the maintainer of GitCandy (ie. **[Aimeast](https://github.com/Aimeast)**) and kindly request from him to update to a more recent LibGit2Sharp version.

Comment: That ticket looks like related. However I updated the LibGit2Sharp NuGet package to the latest (0.21.0.176 currently), and compiled GitCandy with that. I still have this error. But I'll double check.

Comment: You brought my attention to Bonobo, maybe I'll end up with that, if it works out of the box :)